# How to autimatically calculate age when user input her birthdate in a registration form using javascript and thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, kotlin, thymeleaf

> I want To automatically calculate the age of a user when he/she
> entered her birthdate in a registration form.I am using Thymeleaf and
> JavaScritpt for Frontend ,But I am not able to calculate the age
> automatically when user enter her birthdate. I generate the
> registration field dynamically, But I do not know how to calculate the
> age .I am new to thymeleaf.
> Here is my codes
> SignUpForm.html

```
 <div class="singup-form">
                <form id="form_signup">
                    <input id="id" th:field="*{id}" type="hidden"/>
                    <div th:each="item,iterStat : *{form}" >
<!--                        <label th:label="${str.getLabel()}" th:type="${str.getType()}" th:text="${str.value}" ></label>-->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label th:for="${item.name}" th:text="${item.label}"></label>
                            <div th:if="${item.validation == 'dob'}" >
                                <input class="form-control" th:id="${item.name}" th:name="${item.name}" th:placeholder="${item.placeholder}" th:required="${item.required}"
                                       th:type="${item.type}" th:attr="max=${#dates.format(#dates.createNow(), 'MM-dd-yyyy')}" />
                            </div>
                            <div th:unless="${item.validation == 'dob'}" >
                                <input class="form-control" th:id="${item.name}" th:name="${item.name}" th:placeholder="${item.placeholder}" th:required="${item.required}"
                                       th:type="${item.type}"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                   </div>
```

> Advertisement.kt

```
class Advertisement(
val form:ArrayList<Form>?=null,
)

class Form(
    val type:String="",
    val required:Boolean,
    val label:String="",
    val placeholder:String="",
    val name:String="",
    val value:String="",
    val validation:String="",
    val min:Int,
)
```

> SignUp.kt

```
package com.ape.model

data class SignUp(
    val id:Int,
    val email:String?="",
    val login_type:String?="",
    val dob:String?=""
)

data class ModelSignUp(
    val firstname:String?="",
    val month:String?="",
    val day:String?="",
    val year:String?="",
    val email:String?="",
    val phone_number:String?="",
)
```

> Signup.html

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

        var minAge = 18;
        function _calcAge() {
            var date = new Date(document.getElementById("date").value);
            var today = new Date();

            var timeDiff = Math.abs(today.getTime() - date.getTime());
            var age1 = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)) / 365;
            return age1;
        }
        //Compares calculated age with minimum age and acts according to rules//
        function _setAge() {

            var age = _calcAge();
            //alert("my age is " + age);
            if (age < minAge) {
                alert("You are not allowed into the site. The minimum age is 18!");
            } else

                alert("Welcome to my Site");
            window.open(main.htm, _self);

        }


    </script>
```

> I am not able to calculate users age how can I users age
> How can I calculate the age

Comment: Look for [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) and it's documentation. It will be easier and really accurate to make something like `if( moment(submitedBirthDate) > moment().subtract(18, "years") ){ alert("access denied") }`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example for date comparision using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

That library will make exact calculations, accounting leap years etc...

```js
document.querySelector("#birth").addEventListener("change", function(){

  // That is today minus 18 years
  let criteria_date = moment().subtract(18, "years");
  
  // Taht is the submitted date
  let birth = moment(this.value)
  
  // The birth date should be less than the criteria_date
  if(birth > criteria_date){
    alert("Bye kid!")
  } else{
    alert("Welcome")
    // Redirect to your app...
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>

Enter your birth date: <input type="date" id="birth">
```